# Html2Canvas gives half filled single page instead of full content

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jspdf, html2canvas

I have this task where I am using **angular, jspdf, html2canvas, canvas2image** to show up a modal where user can select which items he wishes to **export to PDF**. In the same modal, initially hiding everything below, when the user selects an item  I put that particular div to **become visible**; **renders as preview** for the user.

Modal's Css being:

```
 .pdf-modal-spec{
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:auto;
    max-height:900px;
  }
```

Modal can be scrollable, as user keeps selecting items, **height of to-be exported-to-pdf division height increases(beyond 900px)**. And when I export fully rendered page into pdf **I get only half filled single page(from modal) rendered content**; **it should span to 2-3 page albeit I am getting 2-3 pages but blank**. I don't know where I am going wrong.

My export to pdf program:

```
vm.a4 = [595.28, 841.89];
var form = $(".pdfTemplates");
$('.pdfTemplates').scrollTop(form[0].scrollHeight);
createPDF(form);

function getCanvas(form) {
    form.width((vm.a4[0] * 1.33333) - 50).css('max-width', 'none');
    return html2canvas(form, {
        imageTimeout: 2000,
        background: '#FFFFFF',
        removeContainer: true
    });
}

function createPDF(form) {
  var cache_width = form.width();          
  //create pdf
  getCanvas(form).then(function (canvas) {
      var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      var doc = new jsPDF({
          unit: 'pt',
          format: 'a4',
      });

      // pageHeight= doc.internal.pageSize.height;
      var image = new Image();
      image = Canvas2Image.convertToPNG(canvas);
      doc.addImage(img, 'PNG', 15, 15);
      var corte = (vm.a4[1] * 1.33333) - 30;
      var croppingYPosition = corte;
      var count = (image.height) / corte;
      for (var i = 1; i < count; i++) {
          doc.addPage();
          var sourceX = 0;
          var sourceY = croppingYPosition;
          var sourceWidth = image.width;
          var sourceHeight = corte;
          var destWidth = sourceWidth;
          var destHeight = sourceHeight;
          var destX = 0;
          var destY = 0;
          var canvas1 = canvas;
          canvas1.setAttribute('height', corte * i);
          canvas1.setAttribute('width', destWidth);
          var ctx = canvas1.getContext("2d");
          ctx.drawImage(image, sourceX,
                               sourceY,
                               sourceWidth,
                               sourceHeight,
                               destX,
                               destY,
                               destWidth,
                               destHeight);
          var image2 = new Image();
          image2 = Canvas2Image.convertToPNG(canvas1);
          var image2Data = image2.src;
          doc.addImage(image2Data, 'PNG', 15, 15);
          croppingYPosition += destHeight;
      }
      doc.save('firstPDF.pdf');
      document.getElementsByClassName('pdfTemplates')[0].style.width = '100%';
  });          
}
```

Comment: To be more precise I want to convert overflowed <div id="pdfTemplates"> to PDF. Even if I set overflow of the div to visible or auto html2canvas only exports visible part of div to PDF leaving the rest. I have done some R&D but I couldn't find anything that fulfills my expectation. Please help...

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?  I am dealing with the same thing where the content in the pdf to print shows only half of the table.